# Google Analytics using regex for a search and replace filter to remove string after a?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to write a search and replace filter to remove the tracking code appended to URL. I need to remove the string after the question mark. I have no idea where to even start.

/folder/apps.aspx?lots-of-tracking-blah

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
Filter Field: Request URI
Search String: ^/folder/apps\.aspx\?.*
Replace String: ^/folder/apps\.aspx
```